# Why did Ajax not start with the Oxygen Chamber?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Why did Ajax not start with the Oxygen Chamber to create Dead-pools mutation?

It seems that that was the last and finally way to bring out his mutation, and if Ajax was doing this to sell the mutated people , would it not have been more efficient to use the Oxygen chamber?

Comment: My guess is there is a good chance it could kill the person. Would be kid of stressful on the ol' heart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The punchbowl is clearly a highly unsafe piece of kit. Most humans would not survive a two day session of oxygen deprivation and heart failure.

> **Ajax:** *Adrenaline acts as a catalyst for the serum, so we're gonna have to make you suffer. If you're lucky, your mutant genes will
>   activate and manifest in a spectacular fashion. If not, well, we'll
>   have to keep on hurting you. In new and different ways, each more
>   painful than the last. **Until you finally mutate... or die.***

Ajax, by this point in the film is getting pretty frustrated both with *his lack of success in triggering a mutation* and with *Wade's attitude in general*. He decides to kill two birds with one stone by subjecting him to potentially fatal torture in the hopes that it either triggers a mutation, kills him or at the very least **shuts him up.**

> **Ajax:** ***If this doesn't unlock your mutation, then, well, nothing will.***
>
> *What we're gonna do is lower the oxygen concentration in the air to the exact point you feel like you're suffocating. If your brain wave's
>   slowing and you're about to pass out, then we'll turn up the O2. If
>   your heart rate slows meaning you're able to catch your breath, we'll
>   turn it back down. And that's where we'll leave you.*